# Alterar Ip ao fazer um solicitação Curl em php

Tags: php, libcurl

Olá, tudo certo?

Tenho uma função que ela recebe um termo de busca, vai google e retorna um ponto específico da página nesse termo de busca.

Tudo funcionando bonitinho, exceto pelo fato que em um determinado momento o google reconhece com atividade anormal e não permite mais o acesso.

Fazendo um pesquisa vi que é possível utilizar o curlopt_proxy para alterar o ip de consulta, forjando um tcp. Porém ao incluir o curlopt_proxy em meu código o retorno é totalmente em branco. Não sei o que houve.

```
    $Ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=x64&q='.$Busca.'&Num=1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '66.96.200.39:80');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $conteudo = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

O `CURLOPT_PROXY` define o IP do proxy que quer utilizar. O proxy pode ser `http` (padrão), `socks4` ou `socks5`.

Isto é indicado na documentação: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html.

---

Você não pode definir qualquer IP arbitrariamente, afinal, você quer também obter a resposta. *Tecnicamente, é possível forjar IPs no TCP, mas você não conseguirá obter qualquer resultado. Seja como for, o  `CURLOPT_PROXY` não tem esse intuito, o `CURLOPT_PROXY` **não** forja/altera os pacotes TCP para outro IP arbitrário*.

O `CURLOPT_PROXY` estabelece uma conexão com um servidor proxy, ele irá reencaminhar sua requisição. No final, o servidor final (o Google) verá o IP do proxy (e não verá o seu IP real).

---

Você deve adquirir proxies (pesquise no Google por "buy proxies"). Existem diversos tipos de proxies diferentes, deverá achar um que melhor sirva para o seu caso de uso. Alternativamente, você pode criar o seu próprio proxy, desde que possua diversos IPs... Basta configurar um servidor de proxy (como Squid Proxy Server) e então ele alternará entre os IPs que você possui. Mas, novamente, você precisa adquirir os IPs, e esses IPs serão os que o Google verá. *A diferença é que, você pode ter um único servidor, e vários IPs de saida.*

Você também pode tentar utilizar proxies gratuitos (pesquise por "free proxies") e terá algo como o http://www.freeproxylists.net. Ou, também pode optar por utilizar o Tor ou I2P.

Para testar, pode fazer uma requisição para o `https://api.myip.com` (ao invés do google) para ver o seu IP. Se a requisição via curl tiver um IP diferente do seu dispositivo, então é porque o proxy está configurado corretamente.

*Obviamente, proxies públicos (e gratuitos) são utilizados por qualquer pessoa e pode não resolver o seu problema. Afinal, outras pessoas estão utilizando eles para fazer requisições ao Google.*

---

Uma vez que tiver o IP do proxy que deseja utilizar especifique-o no `CURLOPT_PROXY`. Além disso, remova o `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE`, ou defina ele adequadamente.

Para ver qual o erro está ocorrendo com sua requisição, adicione um `echo curl_error($ch)`.